# GWT: Best practice for unit testing / mocking JSNI methods?

Tags: java, javascript, unit-testing, gwt, jsni

I have a class which uses JSNI to retrieve JSON data stored in the host page:

```
protected native JsArray<JsonModel> getModels() /*-{
    return $wnd.jsonData;
}-*/;
```

This method is called, and the data is then translated and process in a different method. How should I unit test this class, since I'm not able to instantiate (or seemingly mock?) JsArray?

What is the best way to unit test JSNI methods at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface approach is the best approach, and not necessarily an overkill. As to the problem of *actually testing the method* - well, if it is just reading from $wnd.jsonData, there isn't any merit in testing the method. You are better off writing a server side test that confirms you have the right data in the host page.

If you really have some logic in a native method, you are better off writing a selenium/jsunit test case.