# JUnit for a class that contains native method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to create a unit test for a class that contains a native method. Any propositions how to achieve this because I'm getting as expected a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` when I try go create an instance in the unit test.

Comment: actually here is the answer that i was logging for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543462/gwt-best-practice-for-unit-testing-mocking-jsni-methods

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the folder containing your dll to your `-Djava.library.path` configuration for your unit test. This will vary depending on how you're running it. If it's through your IDE, you can set it in there. If it's with maven, you should be able to set that through the surefire plugin http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine.

Comment: yep u correct if my native code was c/c++ but mine is javascipt and i was wandering is it there any 'standard' way to mockup this native methods